# Python script with global in loop keeps increasing memory size

Tags: python, plotly, global-variables

I am working on a Dash/Plotly server that uses an external function to load data. The idea is there is a background process (outside of the server script) that is running and updating the data source files, so every couple of hours the script running the Dash server calls the function that loads the data and regenerates the figures that it saves to the global variable (which is defined in the data loading function), and afterwards the script terminates the app.run_server() process and restarts it.

This all works as expected, with new data being loaded in the background, the server starting and stopping, and new data being made available on the website.

The problem I have, however, is that with each call to the data loading function, the memory use just keeps multiplying so the old data from all the previous loads stays, and I do not know why or how to resolve the issue. I was able to create a very basic script (without actually starting the Dash server) that replicates the problem:

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
def load_data():
    global figs_all
    
    Npts = 100000
    Nplots = 100
    Nsubplots = 5
    
    figs_all = {}
    
    for ii in range(0,Nplots):
        title = str(ii)
        print(title)
        fig = go.FigureWidget( layout={'width': 1600, 'height': 800})
        for jj in range(0,Nsubplots):
            xx = np.random.rand(Npts)
            yy = np.random.rand(Npts)
            fig.add_scattergl(x=xx, y=yy, mode='markers', name=title)
        figs_all[title] = fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
       
    load_data()
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        load_data()
```

So, even though in the function the global is reassigned to {}, with every iteration it just keeps growing. When I check the size of `figs_all` it is only 4704 bytes each iteration. I've tried placing ```del figs_all`` at various places, but nothing works.

What am I missing here?

I've tried placing `del figs_all` at various places, but nothing works.

Expecting memory usage to not keep multiplying each iteration.